# jQuery click function / if statement not working

Tags: jquery, arrays, if-statement, onclick

Can someone explain to me why this doesn't work and what needs to be changed? I'm trying to have 3 icons that perform different actions when clicked.

```
 var array = [
        {val : 1, icon: 'fa-bolt'},
        {val : 2, icon: 'fa-exclamation'},
        {val : 3, icon: 'fa-undo-alt'}
    ];


$(array).each(function() {
   var $item = $('<i>');
   $item.attr('value', this.val).attr('class', 'fas fa-2x ' + this.icon + ' item-class');
   $body.append($item);
});


$('.item-class').on('click', function(){
    if ($(this).val() === '1') {
      //do stuff
    }
    if ($(this).val() === '2') {
      //do stuff
    }
    if ($(this).val() === '3') {
      //do stuff
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is in this line:

```
$('.item-class').on('click', function(){
```

The **svg elements** created by fontawesome are not yet there.  You need to delegate the click event handler like:

```
$body.on('click', '.item-class', function (e) {
```

A second mystake is in this line:

```
$(this).val()
```

The value now is an attribute of svg element.

change it to:

```
$(this).attr('value')
```

```js
var $body = $('body');
var array = [
    {val: 1, icon: 'fa-bolt'},
    {val: 2, icon: 'fa-exclamation'},
    {val: 3, icon: 'fa-undo-alt'}
];


$(array).each(function () {
    var $item = $('<i/>');
    $item.attr('value', this.val).attr('class', 'fas fa-2x ' + this.icon + ' item-class');
    $body.append($item);
});


$body.on('click', '.item-class', function (e) {
    var clickedValue = $(this).attr('value');
    console.log(clickedValue);
    if (clickedValue === '1') {
        //do stuff
    }
    if (clickedValue === '2') {
        //do stuff
    }
    if (clickedValue === '3') {
        //do stuff
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/js/all.js"></script>
```

Comment: Worked! Thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

You can add the `onClick` attribute, something like this:

```
$(array).each(function() {
  var $item = $('<i>');
  $item
    .attr('value', this.val)
    .attr('class', 'fas fa-2x ' + this.icon + ' item-class')
    .attr('onClick', 'show('+this.val+')');
  $('body').append($item);
});

function show(value) {
  console.log(value)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use value attribute for **i** element ? This is not HTML compliant.

You can use **data-*** attributes :

```
$item.data('value', this.val).attr('class', 'fas fa-2x ' + this.icon + ' item-class');
```

And in your loop :

```
// it will return int type, don't test with string
if ($(this).data('value') === 1) {
```

**$(this).val()** works only for input, here you just add **value** attribute on HTML element.